# How to count number of Tuesdays in month using for loops?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Can somebody advise how to write this code? I'm afraid of making mistakes

```
n = 30
y = int(input("Tuesday's date:"))

def func(date):
    for y in n:
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output? Also, don't be afraid of making mistakes. Everyone starts from the very basic. Think about the problem and show us your honest attempt and we'll be ready to help!

Comment: Why use loops here ? Can't you just divide the day by 7 ?

Comment: maybe, can you please introduce the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 30
y = int(input("Tuesday's date:"))
def func(date):
    if date <= (n - 28):
        return 5    # In a 30 days month, if the first tuesday is the 1st or #2nd, there will be 5 tuesdays, else 4. If there are 31 days, the first #tuesday can be the 3rd
    return 4
```

Comment: tnx for your code)

Comment: how to print the result?

Comment: Simply print(func(y))

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows. `for i in range(1, monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1]):` loops into each day of the month, than each weekday is compared to `weekdaynumber`

```
import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

weekdaynumber=1 #Mon:1, Tue:2, ...

count=0
now = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in range(1, monthrange(now.year, now.month)[1]):
    
    if datetime.date(now.year, now.month, i).weekday() == weekdaynumber:
        count += 1

print (count)
```

Comment: tnx for your code, but it shows some errors, maybe we can just - 1 day from some period

Comment: @Ftklee which error? Please copy and paste it here. I tried it and worked

Comment: now it works, but sometimes number of Tuesdays can be 5( if the start date was 2 for example)

Comment: @Ftklee this script prints out the number of weekdays in the current month. To print the number of weekdays in another month, instead of `now = datetime.datetime.now()` use `now = datetime.datetime(year, month, dayofmonth) `